# A Proof for Prime Numbers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, prime-numbers

**Show that among k-digit numbers, one in about every 2.3k is a prime.**

How can we prove this question? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$10^k\le x < 10^{k+1}\implies \ln 10^k\le \ln x < \ln 10^{k+1}\implies$
$k\ln 10\le\ln x<(k+1)\ln 10$, where $ln 10\approx2,3$.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the prime number theorem! :)

Comment: do you mean π(x) = x/lnx

Comment: I do refer to that theorem.

Comment: How can I use it? When I plug k in the equation above I get nothing :)

Comment: @odd: Plug in $x=10^k$ and $x=10^{k+1}$, respectively.